# Is there a way for me to limit how long I am reading in data from a sensor using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a CSV file using acceleration data from my FitBit. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import { display } from "display";
import * as document from "document";

const accelLabel = document.getElementById("accel-label");
const accelData = document.getElementById("accel-data");

const header = ["X","Y","Z"]
const delimiter = ', '

let newheader = header.join(delimiter)+'\n';

let csv = newheader;

const sensors = [];

if (Accelerometer) {
  const accel = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 1 });
  //const obj = {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"};
   accel.addEventListener("reading", () => { //put your reading into here //toFixed is the same as round(x,1) //? is like an if else
   let data = [accel.x, accel.y, accel.z];
   csv += data.join(delimiter)+"\n";
    
 });
  sensors.push(accel);
  accel.start();
} else {
  accelLabel.style.display = "none";
  accelData.style.display = "none";
}
```

I only want it to populate the file for ~10 seconds. Is there a way to limit how long this program runs for?

There are likely libraries I can use but I am writing this in FitBit Studio, and am not sure how that affects the libraries I can/ can't use.

Comment: removeEventListener or setTimeout?

Comment: I don't think removeEventListener() has any parameter that lets you set a time limit. setTimeout() looks like it should work though! Let me give that a try.

Comment: you can put the removeeventlistner in the set timeout. and your addeventfunction in a seperate function.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() worked perfect. I altered it a little so that it looks a little more like this:

```
...
function accelread(){
   accel.addEventListener("reading", () => {
    //put your reading into here //toFixed is the same as round(x,1) //? is like an if else
    let data = [accel.x, accel.y, accel.z]; //setTimeout()
    csv += data.join(delimiter)+"\n";
   });
}; 

if (Accelerometer) {
  const accel = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 1 });
  setTimeout(accelread(),3000);
  //const obj = {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"};
 });
...
```

It's not a finished product, and I have no way to test it quite yet because the FitBit simulator I am using to test the app doesn't actually have any acceleration data, but the idea stands.

Comment: That code looks like it will start reading from your accelerometer after 3 seconds, but I don't see anything there that will stop it from taking readings after any specific amount of time has passed. Is this all your code, and are you sure it's working? I'd have expected to see `addEventListener` called immediately, then `setTimeout` to be called afterwards with a callback that will call `removeEventListener`, like @Strella has suggested in a comment on the question.